# Flutter Firebase : How to find all auth error codes?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using Flutter Firebase auth latest version and I am trying to sign up the user with :

```
try {
  UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: "barry.allen@example.com",
    password: "SuperSecretPassword!"
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
    print('The password provided is too weak.');
  } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
    print('The account already exists for that email.');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

The problem is `e.code` returns a string depending on the error and somehow I can not find all the error codes so I can do an exhaustive UI response. e.g `user-not-found`. How may I find all the error codes to include them in other if statements?

Comment: See this : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Error

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour does not cover `email-already-in-use`, i think this is not the same as Flutter err codes

Comment: Also : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.AuthError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the possible errors in the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth-class.html) for the Flutter firebase_auth package.

For instance, the [createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/createUserWithEmailAndPassword.html) method has the following possible errors:

> - email-already-in-use: Thrown if there already exists an account with    the given email address.
> - invalid-email: Thrown if the email address is not valid.
> - operation-not-allowed: Thrown if email/password accounts are not    enabled. Enable email/password accounts in the Firebase Console,
>   under the Auth tab.
> - weak-password: Thrown if the password is not strong enough.

It's the same for the other methods that throw errors.